# Not getting Spring + forEach loop to work

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I'm trying to display a list of messages, but nothing appears. If I debug the `homeUser()` method below, I can see that the *messages* list does contain a list of messages.

In the jsp page homeUser, IntelliJ indicates that `${messages}` references the right model.

So why on earth does nothing appear?

```
@RequestMapping("/user_home")
public String homeUser(Model model) {
    logger.info("homeUser called");
    List<Message> messages = messageService.getAllMessages();
    model.addAttribute("messages", messages);
    return "userHome";
}
```

---

```
 <c:forEach var="message" items="${messages}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ${message.author}
                    <br/>
                    ${message.text}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: can you post the message class ?

Comment: `Message` class should contain `getAuthor()` and `getText()` methods?

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Answer (score 1):

In message class, You must have public getter and setter method

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons for this i guess.

1. Your Message class doesn't has proper getter and setters for the fields you're trying to access.
2. In  your JSP, you have